# Why doesn't java -version return anything with Oracle's JRE 7?

Tags: java, oracle, jre, update-alternatives

I've been following [these](https://askubuntu.com/a/56119) steps and got up to the check version of new JRE installation part but `java -version` doesn't return anything.

I have run `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/bin/java`.

It returned `update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in auto mode` so it seems I did that part right.

It might have something to with environmental variables, e.g. JAVA_HOME and PATH but I'm not sure how to set them.

Answer (score 1):

When installing java I use the following steps and they always work without fail:

1. Download latest tar from [the Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
2. Extract the contents and move the folder into:

   `/usr/lib/jvm`
3. Install Java alternatives:

   `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/bin/jvm/<jreName>/bin/java 1`
4. Update alternatives (generally is not necessary if you are installing your first Java version but obviously does not hurt to run just to be sure):

   `sudo update-alternatives --config java`
5. Provide the link to the plugin for your browser:

   `ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/<jreName>/amd64/libnpjp2.so .mozilla/plugins/`

These steps have always worked for me without a single issue. If you are running into any troubles after following these (maybe step 4 could be all you need), then please post more information like:

- What `java -version` actually displays (or is it literally blank?)
- The results of `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

In my experience, I have never seemed to need `JAVA_HOME` and currently have perfectly working versions of Java with no variable set.

Comment: That's almost exactly the same as [what I've been doing](http://askubuntu.com/a/56119). Sorry for the laaaaate reply.

Comment: No worries, does java -version return anything at all? Or just an incorrect output? What version of Ubuntu are you on?